# How can I substitute an array for macro like keyword in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am defining a lot of arrays of structs in a module. e.g.

```
my $array = [
   {
      Field1 => "FieldValue1"
   },
   {
      #etc...
   },
];
my $array2 = [
   {
      Field1 => "FieldValue1"
   },
   {
      #etc...
   },
];
```

I often repeat sequences of structs. For instance I might have five { Field1 => "FieldValue1" } structs in a row. Is it possible to save the sequence of structs in some data structure and insert that into my arrays?

e.g.

```
my $array3 = [ $Field1, $Field1, $Field1 ]; # $Field1 is a sequence of structs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers above work well for their own purposes, but they were not exactly what I wanted.

I ended up usin `push()` to create the arrays. `$templatearray1` and `$templatearray2` are arrays of structs. Push()'s behavior is to not insert the array reference. Instead it inserts the elements of the arrays.
e.g.

```
my $myarray = [];
push(@$myarray, @$templatearray1);
push(@$myarray, @$templatearray2);
push(@$myarray, @$templatearray1);
push(@$myarray, @$templatearray2);
push(@$myarray, @$templatearray1);
push(@$myarray, @$templatearray2);
push(@$myarray, (
   {
      key1 => 'blah1',
      key2 => 'blah2',
   },
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but they will all wind up copies of each other.  So editing the first one will change all of them.  Instead use `map`.

```
my $array3 = [ map {Field1 => "FieldValue1"}, 1..5 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time that you find yourself repeating boilerplate code, Perl usually has a way around it.

I am not entirely clear what you want to do, but you could do something like this:

```
sub make_struct {
    {Field1 => "FieldValue1"}
}

my $array = [map make_struct, 1 .. 10];  # array with 10 hashes

sub make_struct_array {[map make_struct, 1 .. $_[0]]}

my $array2 = make_struct_array 20;  # array with 20 hashes
```

So in other words, write a subroutine that returns a new data structure for you.  The subroutine can take a variety of options if you need to customize the structure.

Comment: That sounds great. What if I wanted to interleave one particular struct between two sequences of make_struct? e.g. my $array = [make_struct, { myCustomStruct => "blah" }, make_struct];